# Neo4j language support

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I'm a total noob in graph databases, but I still want to do my thesis in a graph database integration into the organization that I work.
After a small period of time I started to build my database and I think there is no Greek character support.
Is it true?
Can I do anything to solve the problem???

Comment: What did you actually try to do? Neo4j supports UTF-8 as character data.

Comment: Try to explicitly specifiy that you want to use UTF-8. See https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/rabbithole/issues/25 for a couple of hints.